# Viewing, building & debugging Borland C++ Builder project in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c++builder, c++builder-2006

I would like to use VC2010 to handle a BCB 2006 project I have. I do not want to convert the code to VC since much UI will need to be ported. I just want to be able to view build & debug from VS IDE.

Viewing: I assume once I create VS projects for the native BCB code viewing will be possible, although the UI editor will not.

Building: I found the "C++ Native Multi-Targeting" option of VS, although I'm not sure on what to set the different options there to (Daffodil is mentioned as helpful although I'm not sure what the added value is over existing functionality).

Debugging: not sure how to do this at all from within VS. There are some stand alone console tools that convert debug info files e.g. tds2pdb (wheres the documentation link?).

If anyone has experience with such a task I would thank you for any advice.

Answer (score 4):

No. The C++ Builder IDE is a stand-alone, separate Win32 executable that has nothing to do with VC or Visual Studio, and can't be embedded in it in any way. You'll have to use C++ Builder itself to view, build, and debug it's apps; there's no way to do so as part of Visual Studio.

Even simply using the C++ Builder code will most likely not be possible if there is any UI involved at all. C++ Builder's GUI components are based on the Visual Component Library (VCL) that it shares with Delphi, and therefore it uses a Delphi Object Pascal compiler to build those parts of the application. There are also data types and set operations that VC will not understand or support, and some special `#pragmas` and `#hppemit` statements the VC compiler wouldn't be able to use.

Comment: My question does not deal with using VC tools to build C++ Builder components but to use C++ Builder tools from within VC environment: I just want the IDE...

Comment: You misunderstood my answer. I'm saying it's not possible to use C++ Builder code or tools from within Visual Studio or VC at all, whether it's the IDE or just the code. I'll rephrase it to make it more clear.